# How to pick service name in WSO2 using Log Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. When i use log mediator, i want it to also log the proxy service name in which log mediator is being used. Is there any property defined in wso2 that i can use?

**Problem:**

In the following log mediator I am using "Server_IP" and "Server_HOST" property to pick up the Server IP and Server Host name. So is there any property from which i can pick up the service name.

**Log Mediaator:**

```
 <log level="full" separator="LogMediator" description="LoggerTemplate">
    <property name="ServerIP" expression="get-property('SERVER_IP')"/>
    <property name="ServerHost" expression="get-property('SERVER_HOST')"/>
    </log>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use the `$ctx:proxy.name` expression for your property mediator:

```
<log level="custom"> 
    <property name="proxyName" expression="$ctx:proxy.name"/>
</log>
```

**Output**:

> [2015-02-06 06:24:07,161]  INFO - LogMediator proxyName = vfsTest

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you also help me that if i want to pick up the Sequence Name in which i am using this Log Mediator. Can i do that ..?

Comment: @omerkhalid: I do not see a Synapse constant for that. The list is [here](https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.synapse.SynapseConstants.PROXY_SERVICE). I have found multiple tutorials from WSO2 developers where they are hardcoding the sequence names in the `value` attribute of the property mediator, so there might not be a dynamic way of doing it. Example from one tutorial: `<sequence name="fileWriteSequence"><log level="custom"><property name="sequence" value="fileWriteSequence"/></log> ... </sequence>`.